# Kendo UI Grid jQuery top cell value populates other cells within this column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to update all rows inside one column. Each column would have its own input which will update the rest of the rows. Currently I have an existing edit batch table. I was wondeing if it was possible to:

1. select a column (maybe with checkbox)
2. Row 1 is empty, however will trigger a function
3. This function takes the input value (which the user will type) of row 1 cell and populate this value for every row inside the that column.

COL 1 || COL 2

---

row 1 || row 1

---

row Z || row Z

After this the user should still be able to activate the cancel button and the original data appears back in the table. The table data should not be saved unless the saved button is pressed.

I've tried a fucntion using a button where we would execute row.set(column, value), however this would refresh the grid table and the original data would reappear.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use the [Spreadsheet](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/index) widget instead?

Comment: We currently have an existing batch editing table and it's been requested to modify every row within a selected column. We should be able to select this column and type the changes inside an input.